# Change hammerJs v1.0.7 to newest hammerjs with KineticJs

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, kineticjs, hammer.js

i am using hammerJs V1.0.7 with no error and when i want to change to the lastest version of HammerJs, but i show me a error , **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'touchAction' of undefined** , any know how to solve the error? thanks, and i am doing a binding of multitouch to my image to scale and rotate it.

```
 var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        image : imageObj,
        draggable : true,
        x: stage.getWidth()/4,
        y: stage.getHeight()/4,
        width: stage.getWidth() / 2,
         height: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        visible: false,
    });
    layer1.add(image);
    layer1.draw();

    var startScale = 1;
    var startRotate = 0;

    var hammertime = Hammer(image);

    hammertime.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });
    hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });

    hammertime.on("rotate", function(e) {
    startScale = image.pinchX();
    startRotate = image.rotation();
    }).on("rotate", function(e) {
       image.pinch({
    x : startScale * e.gesture.pinch,
    y : startScale * e.gesture.pinch,
});
    image.rotation(startRotate + e.gesture.rotation);
    layer1.draw();
    });
```

Comment: I made integration KineticJS with HammerJS. I was not tested integration with latest HammerJS. Once upon time I will look into this soon.

Comment: ok thanks :) but will that be any time soon?? like within this week? or what? thanks